# How to reset an integer if the user not opening the app in the morning? ANDROID

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there any possible way to do this:

```
if ( 5 AM < now < 11:30 AM )
{
if the user didn't click a specific button, at this specific time, then:
x=0;
}
```

Comment: Learn basic Java and Android, then you'll answer your own question. It's really unclear what you're asking too.

Comment: You can use the alarm manager to run your code then... but it would be easier to record a timestamp when they *do* push it, and then whenever you want to know, see if one (or more) of these special periods has elapsed since the last time they were recorded to have pushed the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the time libraries, depending on your minimum API level, to get the times. You can look closer into the documentation to get a better idea of how to use it. Both the code snippets I have below are very similar.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html

I would try using these two functions (copied and pasted from Android Documentation)

```
public boolean after (Time that)
//Added in API level 3
//Returns true if the time represented by this Time object occurs after the given time.
//Parameters --  
//that a given Time object to compare against
//Returns -- 
//true if this time is greater than the given time
```

Similar to previous statement

```
public boolean before (Time that)
//Added in API level 3 
//Return true if the time represented by this Time object occurs before the given time.
//Returns --
//true if this time is less than the given time
```

Comment: Thanks, but anyways, I did it in another way, so if user clicked a button the code reads the clock and decide wether the user clicked the same button 36 hours before or not then x=0. You might not understand what I am saying but no problem lol.